How to Run Two Functions in Parallel Simultaneously?
Like, I have two functions, one to move a robot and one to display that movement in Cortona. I have tried using ParallelSubmit, but they are running after each other.
task[[1]]=ParallelSubmit[moverobot[]]
task[[2]]=ParallelSubmit[dislayChange[]]
WaitAll[task]

Is there any way of making this work?
The robot start moving and during that the display writes out received.

Are these functions that run quickly? I think ParallelSubmit is meant for CPU intensive operations. I'm thinking that using ScheduledTasks might be more appropriate.

Some strategies -  We could offer more if we saw the details of your code.
You can try running the two functions simultaneously in Mathematica using parallel computing techniques.
Multiple Kernels:
Configure multiple Wolfram Language kernels to run different commands at the same time. This involves setting up a new kernel and assigning it to a separate notebook, allowing evaluations to be performed concurrently across different notebooks.
Parallelize:
The Parallelize function automatically distributes parts of an evaluation across available kernels and processors. This can be useful if both functions can be expressed as parts of a larger expression that can be evaluated in parallel.
ParallelSubmit and WaitAll:
You can use ParallelSubmit to submit expressions for concurrent evaluation and WaitAll to wait for all concurrent evaluations to finish. This approach allows you to manage the execution of multiple functions explicitly.
SetSharedVariable and SetSharedFunction:
If your functions need to share data or results, you can use SetSharedVariable and SetSharedFunction to synchronize values and function evaluations across subkernels.
